# i am getting no response when i am going to remove product from cart?

Tags: django, python-3.x

## this is my view stuff.

```
 def remove_from_cart(request,id):
      try:
          the_id = request.session['cart_id']
          cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
          print(cart)
    except:
          return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart'))
          cartitem=CartItem.objects.get(id=id)
          cartitem.delete()
      cartitem.cart=None
      cartitem.save()
```

## this is my urlmapping

```
url('^cart/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.remove_from_cart,name='remove_from_cart'),

<a href="{% url 'remove_from_cart' item.id %}">Remove</a>
```

i am getting this on my terminal

**"GET /cart/3/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0**

Answer (score 1):

You have to `return` a `HttpResponse` from a `view`.

```py
from  django.http.response import HttpResponse

def remove_from_cart(request,id):
      try:
          the_id = request.session['cart_id']
          cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
          print(cart)
    except:
          return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart'))
          cartitem=CartItem.objects.get(id=id)
          cartitem.delete()
      cartitem.cart=None
      cartitem.save()

    # Always return a response
    return HttpResponse('saved')
```